# Two possibilities of $X$ to make the sequence $0\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow X\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{2}\longrightarrow 0$ exact.

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, abelian-groups, exact-sequence

I am working on an exercise in homological algebra asking to find the possibilities of $X$ such that the sequence $$0\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow X\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{2}\longrightarrow 0$$ is a short exact sequence.

The exercise says there is only two possibilities of $X$ up to isomorphism.

I can see that one possibility is $X=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ in which case the above sequence also splits, but I don't know another choice of $X$.

If the sequence is exact, we must have $\mathbb{Z}_{2}=X/\mathbb{Z}$, is there any such $X$? I mean, if it is $\mathbb{Z}/X$, then we know that $X=2\mathbb{Z}$, but what should $X$ be if the quotient is "inversed"??

Thank you so much!

Comment: Notice that $2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are isomorphic.

Comment: @EricWofsey why is that? if $\mathbb{Z}$ and $2\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic then $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}=0$, but it should be $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$, right?

Comment: JacobsonRadical, that's your error right there. A group can be isomorphic to its proper subgroup when the quotient is non-trivial. Surely you agree that $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\simeq\Bbb{Z}_2$ and that both $\Bbb{Z}$ and $2\Bbb{Z}$ are infinite cyclic groups, hence isomorphic to each other.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen yeah, I indeed had a misconception there. Thank you so much for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $\mathbb{Z}_2=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.  There are [two possibilities](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Ext#RelationToGroupExtensions) (up to [equivalence of short exact sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_functor#Equivalence_of_extensions)) because [$\text{Ext}_\mathbb{Z}^1\big(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11391/computing-textext-mathbb-z-p-mathbb-z).  The trivial extension (associated to the zero element of $\text{Ext}_\mathbb{Z}^1\big(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})$) is given by the splitting short exact sequence
$$0\to\mathbb{Z} \underset{\iota_0}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}\oplus(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\underset{\pi_0}\twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to 0\,,$$
where $\iota_0(x):=(x,0)$ and $\pi_0(x,y):=y$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $y\in\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.  The nontrivial extension (associated to the unit element of $\text{Ext}_\mathbb{Z}^1\big(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})$) is
$$0\to\mathbb{Z}\underset{\iota_1}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}\underset{\pi_1}\twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to 0\,,$$
where $\iota_1(x):=2x$ and $\pi_1(x):=x+2\mathbb{Z}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Z}$.

As for your confusion, it is not a good idea to write $X/\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ in this situation.  If your exact sequence is
$$0\to \mathbb{Z} \underset{\iota}{\hookrightarrow} X\underset{\pi}{\twoheadrightarrow} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to 0\,,$$
then $X/{\color{red}\iota}(\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.  The map $\iota$ plays a role in making the quotient.  Therefore, even when $X=\mathbb{Z}$, it is still possible to have $X/\iota(\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ despite the fact that $X/\mathbb{Z}\cong 0$.

Comment: Thank you for this nice clarification!!

Comment: One more question, so for a short exact sequence $0\longrightarrow A\longrightarrow_{i} B\longrightarrow_{j} C\longrightarrow 0$, the safest description of $C$ should be $C\cong B/i(A)$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Alright! Thank you so much! I was just following the class note and definition from Wolfram Mathworld. Both use $C\cong B/A$, but it's like this exercise is a strong sign indicating the danger of using such a description.

Comment: It is a hand-waving notation, and supposed to mean $C/i(B)$.  Mathematicians write something like this a lot, but they all know what the intended meaning would be.  For a learner, it can cause a confusion.

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much for clarifying this out!